# Botman conversation don't save data to mysql db

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, mariadb, botman

Hi guys I write to you because I implemented a conversation in my bot telegram developed with Botman but unfortunately I can't save the data of the object created in my mysql db. In the Laravel log check the error "local.ERROR: SQLSTATE [HY000] [2002] Connection timed out (SQL: insert into ..." but if I try to execute the command "php artisan migrate: fresh" I can fill the db correctly and then to connect with it.
...

```
class StoryNW extends Conversation
{
    /**
     * Start the conversation.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */

    protected $firstname;
    protected $email;
    public $user;
    protected $userbot;
    protected $checkUserDB;
    protected $attachment;

    public function run()
    {
        $this->i_01();
    }

    public function stopsConversation(IncomingMessage $message)
    {
        if ($message->getText() == 'stop') {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }


    public function skipsConversation(IncomingMessage $message)
    {
        if ($message->getText() == 'pause') {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }


    /** I_01 **/
    public function i_01()
    {
        $this->say('start conversation');

        UserBot::create([
            'name' => $this->bot->getUser()->getFirstName().' '.$this->bot->getUser()->getLastName(),
            'email' => 'pippo@yahoo.it',
            'username' => $this->bot->getUser()->getUsername(),
            'chat_id' => $this->bot->getUser()->getId()
        ]);*/

        $this->say('user saved');
    }
}


ERRO LOG: 
SQLSTATE[HY000][2002] Connection timed out (SQL: insert into user_bots (name, email, username, chat_id, updated_at, created_at) values (Gianfri, pippo2@yahoo.it, ganfritolt, 18261059, ...)){"exception":"[object] (Illuminate\\Database\\QueryException(code: 2002): SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection timed out (SQL: insert into user_bots (name, email, username, chat_id, updated_at, created_at) values (Gianfri, pippo2@yahoo.it, ganfritolt, 18261059, ...)) at .../Database/Connection.php:664,PDOException(code: 2002): SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection timed out

/* My config/database.php */

'connections' => [

        'sqlite' => [
            'driver' => 'sqlite',
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', database_path('database.sqlite')),
            'prefix' => '',
        ],

        'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
        ],

        'pgsql' => [
            'driver' => 'pgsql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '5432'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'prefix' => '',
            'schema' => 'public',
            'sslmode' => 'prefer',
        ],

        'sqlsrv' => [
            'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '1433'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'prefix' => '',
        ],

    ],

/* .env */

APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=mykey
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost

LOG_CHANNEL=stack

TELEGRAM_TOKEN=tokenbot

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=ipserver
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=namemydb
DB_USERNAME=myusername
DB_PASSWORD=mypassword
...

TYPE DB: MySQL 10.1.44-MariaDB
```

Comment: Where is the code failing? it would be good to have more detailed error message

Comment: @ChristopheHubert this is the error with more details:

Comment: SQLSTATE[HY000][2002] Connection timed out (SQL: insert into `user_bots` (`name`, `email`, `username`, `chat_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (Gianfri, pippo2@yahoo.it, ganfritolt, 18261059, ...)){"exception":"[object] (Illuminate\\Database\\QueryException(code: 2002): SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection timed out (SQL: insert into `user_bots` (`name`, `email`, `username`, `chat_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (Gianfri, pippo2@yahoo.it, ganfritolt, 18261059, ...)) at .../Database/Connection.php:664,PDOException(code: 2002): SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection timed out

Comment: please add it to the question as formatted code - not in comment

Comment: as well, seems like the connection to your db has issues - can you share your .`env` file and you `config/database.php`

Comment: @ChristopheHubert error added to question

Comment: @ChristopheHubert env and config/database.php added to question

Comment: you can connect to your DB directly using the parameters from your .env file?

Comment: @ChristopheHubert how I can do this?